# How to get Directories From WinCe Device using Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I was trying to get Win CE device information using Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity dll from a desktop application. I was able to connect , get system info, get running processes and disconnect. I am trying to fetch directories and files existing on device and i am not able to. If any one knows how to get them , please provide some code samples. That will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CoreCon APIs (Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity) cannot inherently give you a list if files on the device.  It provides some rudimentary capabilities to get device info and push a file, but it's main purpose it to provide an API pipeline to allow you to create your own client tools.  The VSD team did [blog an example of using the CoreCon APIs to get a list of files from a connected device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdteam/archive/2007/11/20/corecon-api-part-ii.aspx) in a console app, which should get you most of the way to what you're after.

Comment: Thanks,I tried the sample code provided in the link. It works great. As per sample code foo.txt is getting created,but its empty. And FileList.exe is getting exited soon, because i never came to thread sleep in that block. Am I Missing something?

Answer (score 2):

When i was going through link given by ctacke, i found some more parts of it available. I went through [CoreCon API - Part V](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdteam/archive/2007/12/06/corecon-api-part-v.aspx) and Followed his steps, it worked. Infact he has a provided a sample application too.